# LoadAndRegisterSheet in Geckofx c#

Tags: c#, css, geckofx

I am trying to load/apply a locally stored CSS file to all pages displayed in geckofx:

```
nsIStyleSheetService SSS = Xpcom.GetService<Gecko.nsIStyleSheetService>("@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1");
var mUri = IOService.CreateNsIUri(@"C:\css.css");
uint a = 1; //replaced SSS.USER_SHEET with uint a: 1 = USER_SHEET
SSS.LoadAndRegisterSheet(mUri, a);
```

The constant SSS.USER_SHEET, does not seem to exist in nsIStyleSheetService. From gecko source the type appears to be uLong, but from my method uint. Also, how can I set my CSS' URI relative to my source directory?

After running, I get a generic exception on line 4 (LoadAnd..):

Exception from HRESULT: 0x804B0012'